# Black screen when switching users on HP laptop (running vista)

Tags: windows-vista, hp-pavilion

Vista machine:
When I switch users I get a black screen for 30+ seconds.
Doesn't seem to matter who is logged in. Delay happens when I click "switch user" but not when I lock the screen and log back in as same user.

Specs:
Windows Vista 64-bit;
HP pavilion dv9710t laptop;
17" screen (best guess is that it has something to do with display settings, not sure)

Comment: I have an Acer, same problem and sometimes when I come back to the switch user screen, it puts me in 800x600 :(

Answer (score 1):

I had it too.  I uninstalled my Spyware Doctor 6.1 from PCTools, and now the Switch User works great.  Check to see if you have a spyware program installed.  bummer they do not work together, but it appears this is it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem or not, but when I log in for the first time after booting my computer, the monitor turns off. My laptop is plugged into a docking station and is always closed, and I need to open it until the built-in display comes on and then close it again. After that, my monitor works perfectly until I next reboot my computer. I don't have this problem when using the laptop as a laptop

Is your laptop connected to an external display? If so, does this work? If not, I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help. Please post more details regarding your setup and when this occurs.

I have an HP laptop running x64 windows, and the problem doesn't seem affected by service pack or Vista edition (although it doesn't happen under Windows 7 RC)

**Edit:** This is not the same problem; I just used the "Switch User" feature and it didn't help.